# IntelliJ: Adding ALL Files to git repository

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea

I have a IntelliJ Project. I shared the project on git just with one class. Now I have much more classes and files. But I was just able to commit the first created class.

I found out, that I can add the other classes in the VCS Tool Window under Local changes. But then I can also just add the classes. I don't have my complete structure and I don't have all the files that are not classes like images etc.

Can someone tell me how I can commit the COMPLETE project and not just all the classes?

Comment: Open a terminal, navigate to the folder where the projects are, type `git add f1 f2 f3 ...` where f1, f2, etc are the names of the files containing the classes

Comment: Right click the root folder of your project>git>add

Answer (score 0):

For adding all files, you can use @dkanejs comment.

If you are planning to commit all files by adding them, then you can do `cmd + k` in Mac (Please edit for adding Windows Shortcut)

[image]

A new window will open up. As you can see in the below picture, files which are modified and not staged will be displaced in `red`. Tick those files.

Give `commit message` in another input box and go ahead with commit.